# Creating a stand alone program from Python 3.6 - with xml files

Tags: python, exe, python-3.6

I want to create a stand-alone program from a Python project.
Part of my data is saved in xml files, so I need them to be a part of the build
Wich program can help me do so?

Thanks,
Avishay

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow Avishay !!! Please go through this link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to create a stand-alone executable program. If your program depends of other files, you can include it in the program using the Pyinstaller [spec files](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle). Spec files contains all the instructions to create your program, including additional data files or missing modules that Pyinstaller cann't find. I strongly recommend you to use it.

You can build your program using Pyinstaller with your script:

```
pyinstaller myprogram.py
```

And a spec file will be automatically generated, then you can edit it and use it for new builds.

Comment: I tried using the pyinstaller but the exe didn't work
When I opened it the prompt justed opened and closed
The program is a GUI with TKinter, I don't know if it changes anything

Comment: Usually programs created with pyinstaller doesn´t work at first time. Open the command line and run your program from there, so you can read the error message. Most Pyinstaller problems are related with importing modules or files that your program needs.